# Javascript move through 12 part array in a circular manner

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a HTML/CSS circle of fifths. I have a circle divided into 12 segments.

[image]

Each segment is represented as an array, C => 1, G => 2 and so on:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

When I click on a segment, take C (1) for example, I want to add a class to that segment (class="segment-1"). I also want to add a class to the previous segment 'F' (class="segment-12") and the next segment 'G' (class="segment-2"). Then I want to add a different class to segments 3, 4 and 5 and finally add different class to segment 6. It would look like this:

[image]

So I want to be able to do this regardless of which segment I click.

Here is my code so far.

```js
var fifths = {
        segments: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
        init: function(){
            this.cacheDOM();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        cacheDOM: function(){
            this.$segments = $('.segment');
            this.$text     = $('.text');
        },
        bindEvents: function(){
            this.$segments.on('click', this.setKey.bind(this));
        },
        setKey: function(e){
            this.$text.removeClass('active');
            $(e.target).addClass('active');
            var selectedSegment = $(e.target).attr('data-segment');
            alert(this.segments.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
                alert(this.segments.slice(0, 3).join(","))
                this.segments.push(this.segments.shift());
            }
        },
    }
    fifths.init();
```

```css
.circle {
        position: relative;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 1em auto;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: rotate(-15deg);
    }
    li {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        transform-origin: 0% 100%;
        border: 1px dashed #aaaaaa;
    }
    .text {
        position: absolute;
        left: -100%;
        width: 200%;
        height: 200%;
        text-align: center;
        transform: skewY(60deg) rotate(15deg);
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .text:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    li:first-child {
        transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }

    li:nth-child(2) {
        transform: rotate(30deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(2) .circle-major {
        transform: rotate(-30deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }

    li:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(4) {
        transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(5) {
        transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(6) {
        transform: rotate(150deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(7) {
        transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(8) {
        transform: rotate(210deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(9) {
        transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(10) {
        transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(11) {
        transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }
    li:nth-child(12) {
        transform: rotate(330deg) skewY(-60deg);
    }


    li:nth-child(13) {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ffffff;
        transform: skewY(0deg) rotate(0deg);
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 110px;
        right: 110px;
    }

    li:hover {
        background: #2ecc71;
        border-color: #3A933A;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .circle-major {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .circle-minor {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .active {
        background: #2ecc71;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .segment-major {
        background: #CC2E4A;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .segment-minor {
        background: #606060;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .segment-diminished {
        background: #5C2ECC;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="circle">
    <li id="segment-1" class="segment" data-segment="1"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">C</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-2" class="segment" data-segment="2"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">G</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-3" class="segment" data-segment="3"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">D</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-4" class="segment" data-segment="4"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">A</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-5" class="segment" data-segment="5"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">E</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-6" class="segment" data-segment="6"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">B</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-7" class="segment" data-segment="7"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">F#</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-8" class="segment" data-segment="8"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">Db</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-9" class="segment" data-segment="9"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">Ab</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-10" class="segment" data-segment="10"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">Eb</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-11" class="segment" data-segment="11"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">Bb</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <li id="segment-12" class="segment" data-segment="12"><div class="text"><span class="circle-major">F</span><br><span class="circle-minor">A</span></div></li>
    <!-- <li><div class="text"></div></li> -->
<ul>
```

As you can see I am stuck, I don't know how to treat the array as circular.

EDIT: So if I click on segment one, how can I target the next segment counter-clockwise in the circle?

Comment: This is a perfect use case for the `%` mod operator. After adding / subtracting, just mod the result by 12. For example if you click segment 11, next 3 segments are `(11 + 1) % 12`, `(11 + 2) % 12`, and `(11 + 3) % 12`. You should probably re-number your `data-segment` attrs to be 0-based, so that they match the zero-based array indexing. this will make your life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this would be a wonderful use-case of the [`%` (modulo) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()):

```
var nextSegmentIndex = (segmentIndex + 1) % 12;
```

If you are going backwards, just check for `x < 0` or `x <= 0` and add `12` if needed (before using the `%` operator). You might need to fill your array in the `[0, 11]` range instead of `[1, 12]` (which is what I do when working with musical notation).